# Changing the icon of an app build with phonegap build

Tags: android, phonegap-build

I am new to mobile app development, so I started to use PhoneGap Build.

My app works fine, but comes with a default icon. How do I change this icon to the icon of my app?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it when you create the new application, or if you already created it, you can replace the default icon.png which is stored inside res->drawable folder.
There you can replace that picture for the one you want.

Comment: thanks for the response . . . i have created it already and i decompiled it to change the icon but after recompiling . . . google play store did not accept it with an error that it is not properly signed

Comment: so i later sign it using SignAPK tool and zipalign it. buh google play store is now saying my apk is signed with a certificate that would soon expire. what can i do next